# How to fix character encoding in sql query

Tags: sql, encoding, db2

I have a db2 database where I store names containing special characters. When I try to retrieve them with an internal software, I get proper results. However when I tried to do the same with queries or look into the db, the characters are stored strangely.

The documentation says that the encoding is utf-8 latin1.
My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT firstn, lastn
FROM unams
WHERE unamid = 12345
```

The user with the given ID has some special characters in his/her name: **é** and **ó**, but the query returns it as **Ă©** and **Ăł**.

Is there a way to convert the characters back to their original form with using some simple SQL function? I am new to databases and encoding, trying to understand the latter by reading [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) but I'm quite lost.

EDIT: Currently sending queries via SPSS Modeler with a proper ODBC driver, the database lies on a Windows Server 2016

Comment: Edit your question to show which tool you use to submit the SQL, and which operating system runs that tool. You are seeing codepage conversion, which is avoidable by correct configuration.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Windows environment variable DB2CODEPAGE to value 1208 ?  You will need to stop and restart your SPSS-Modeler tool for the change to take effect.

Comment: Yes, I get __1208__ as the result of the following query: `SELECT CODEPAGE FROM SYSCAT.DATATYPES WHERE TYPENAME = 'VARCHAR'`

Comment: I feed the data to a (_IdentityInsight_) pipeline that loads it to the DB, when I manually insert a new row with special characters, it shows correctly in the DB and the query also gives back the proper names. I couldn't find how it messed up, that's why I was keen to find a function to recode the results.

Comment: From your comments, it is unclear if you have set the windows system environment variable on your workstation where SPSS-Modeler runs, (from control panel > System > system Properties  > Environment Variables > System Variables > New. Then variable-name: DB2CODEPAGE, variable value: 1208 > OK > OK > OK. then restart.

Comment: Sorry, I misunterstood your previous comment. I did as you suggested, since the variable was missing. It did not solve the problem, the characters are still returned badly.

Comment: Newl, mao has sugggested to verify the codepage setting on ***CLIENT*** side.  Reading a setting from SYSCAT.whatever will get you back the settings from the ***SERVER*** side.  What you are seeing is UTF-8 encoded data sent as-is to the client, and the client interpreting it as some old-style ascii codepage (i.e. the client is unaware that this is utf-8 and skips translation to its own codepage).

Comment: @ErwinSmout indeed! I did a query and get the values from the server, thinking that it's good, but I found out that I misunderstood mao's comment. I have found the environment variable on my local computer, since the client is the modeler, running local. I added the missing __DB2CODEPAGE__ variable with the mentioned value, restarted the system, but it still gives back the letters as before.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the exact version of the SPSS Modeler, and the bitness and edition of the Windows workstation, and the exact version+supplier of the database driver being used by SPSS-Modeler.

Comment: @mao Your help solved the problem, when I set the DB2CODEPAGE variable on the server, then restarted the pipeline, drop the tables, and reload them, the names are shown correctly not only in the db2, but when queried in Modeler. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, the solution was to create a Windows environment variable DB2CODEPAGE=1208 , then restart, then drop and re-populate the tables.

If the applications runs locally on the Db2-server (i.e. only one hostname is involved) then the same variable can be set. This will impact all local applications that use the UTF-8 encoded database.

If the application runs remotely from the Db2-server (i.e. two hostnames are involved) then set the variable on the workstation and on the Windows Db2-server.

Current versions of IBM supplied Db2-clients on Windows will [derive their codepage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/c0006825.html) from the regional settings which might not always render Unicode characters correctly, so using the DB2CODEPAGE=1208 forces the Db2-client CLI drivers to use a Unicode application code page to override this.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (firstn) as (
values ('éó')
--SELECT firstn
--FROM unams
--WHERE unamid = 12345
)
select x.c, hex(x.c) c_hes
from 
  t
, xmltable('for $id in (1 to string-length($s)) return <i>{substring($s, $id, 1)}</i>' 
passing t.firstn as "s" columns tok varchar(6) path '.') x(c);

C C_HEX
- -----
é C3A9
ó C3B3
```

The query above converts the string of characters to a table with each character (`C`) and its hex representation (`C_HEX`) in each row.
You can run it as is to check if you get the same output. It must be as described for a UTF-8 database.
Now try to comment out the line with `values ('éó')` and uncomment the select statement returning some row with these special characters.

If you see the same hex representation of these characters stored in the `firstn` column, then this means, that the string is stored appropriately, but your client tool (SPSS Modeller) can't show these characters correctly due to some reason (wrong font, for example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You code works and returns the mentioned table. Although, when I select a name, that contains and __é__, and run your code on it, it simply shows that what are the hex values of the __Ă__ and __©__ characters (hex C482 and C2A9) that somehow replace the original __é__. The proper conversion would be __é__ -> __Ă©__ -> __é__ but it seems like that the last step is missing when I try to get an entity's name by a query.

Comment: If your internal software works with such data appropriately, then this may work as designed. Data may not be intended to be usable by common / third-party software. But it looks strange indeed. Back to your initial question: if you want to see correct data without your internal software, you probably must understand such an "encoding scheme", and "decode" the data with an appropriate expression/function.

Comment: The problem is that while the internal software can represent the given entities, but one can't do a search where there are special characters in the name. I.e.: I can't search for someone who has a name Aétó Bill, I can only do a search by the ID. That's why I thought that doing the same by queries from Modeler should be handy, if the conversion can be done.

Comment: If I got you right this "internal software" actually places these "wrong" characters to the database. If so, then ask the owner of this "internal software" on why it does such strange things...